# Is there a mushroom head bolt standard for sizes smaller than M4?

Tags: bolting, standards

Is there a standard similar to DIN 603 / ISO 8678 (metric mushroom head square neck bolts) for sizes smaller than M4. DIN 603 only goes down to M5 (please correct me if I'm wrong).

[image]

I did see similar mushroom head bolts used in piano actions (which is what I want them for as well) but I can't find any more info than that.

Basically what I'm trying to find is something like M4 screw/bolt with a smooth mushroom cap and without any driving features (no slot). Like a DIN 660 rivet but with threads. Or a small DIN 603 bolt.

Comment: Are you expecting us to do your shopping for you?

Comment: No, does my question indicate such expectation? What's the point of your comment?

Comment: will button-head's work for you for roundness of the head, or are you looking for the square part of it, to keep the bolt from rotating

Comment: @PeteW slotless truss/mushroom head is the thing I'm looking for, neck doesn't matter

Comment: button-head or cheese-head are the closest thing then, I think, that are common in M3 and smaller. IMO Torx rather than hex-socket or Phillips is worth it, esp. in stainless.

Comment: There's also DIN660, buts those are rivets. Or DIN914 setscrews + DIN1587 domed cap nuts. But it's hard to believe there's no small mushroom machine screw standard. I mean those should be useful in situations where some ant-tampering solution is required...

Comment: Oh I see what you're trying to do now, you want no drive feature at all. You should explain that in the question...

Comment: If the answer is _yes_ we can't tell where to find it. If it's _no_ we're no help either.

Comment: @DDuck well sure, my question is if there is a standard for such parts. If there is, I'm pretty sure I would manage to find a place to get them. No is a valid answer, and it looks like that's the case here.